# Help with definition in abstract algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra

4.10 Definition Let G be a group.

(a) For any non-empty subset X of G we define $<X>$ as the set of all elements of $G$ of the form $$x_{1}^{\epsilon_{1}}*x_{2}^{\epsilon_{2}}******x_{n}^{\epsilon_{n}}$$

where $n \in N$, $x_1,....,x_n \in X$ and $\epsilon_{1},...,\epsilon_{n} \in {1,-1}$. We extend this definition to the empty subset of $G$ by setting $<\emptyset>={1_G}$. Note that one always has $X \subseteq <X>$. In fact, we will prove that $<X>$ is a subgroup of G. It is called the subgroup generated by $X$

This is a little bit confusing to me in the sense that we just allowed $\epsilon_n$ to be $1$ or $-1$, so how come $X \subseteq <X>$? if for example $x_1=x^1_{1}*x_2^0******x^0_n$. Note here that the identity element is not allowed.

Comment: e.g. choose all $\,x_i\ = x.\,$ If we then choose alll $\,\epsilon_i = 1\,$ then we get $\,x^n,\,$ and if all we choose all $\,\epsilon_i = -1\,$ whe get $\,x^{-n}.\,$ If we choose $\,n = 0\, $ (empty product) then we get the identity.

Comment: Hmmm, don't see any reason they couldn't have made it easier and allowed en to be any m.  As you can do xi=xj=xk and do xi^1xj^1xk^1 = xi^3.

Comment: can $x_1$ and and $x_2$ be the same element?

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $n$ is not fixed, i.e.
$$
      \langle X \rangle
  = \{
      x_1^{\epsilon_1} \dotsm x_n^{\epsilon_n}
    \mid
      n \in \mathbb{N},
      x_1, \dotsc, x_n \in X,
      \epsilon_1, \dotsc, \epsilon_n \in \{1,-1\}
    \}
$$
For $x \in X$ we can choose $n = 1$ and $x_1 = x$, $\epsilon_1 = 1$ to get that $x = x_1^{\epsilon_1} \in \langle X \rangle$.

Comment: is that equivalent to saying that we allow $\epsilon=0$?

Comment: can we take take for example $x_1=x$ and $x_2=x^{-1}$ to get the inverse element?